# Is LWJGL's Matrix4f.mul method pre or post multiply?

Tags: java, matrix, lwjgl, matrix-multiplication

Just wondering if LWJGL's Matrix4f.mul method pre or post multiply. Or if theres a way to choose.

Answer (score 5):

According to the javadoc, `Matrix4f.mul` will:

> Multiply the right matrix by the left and place the result in a third matrix.

```
public static Matrix4f mul(Matrix4f left, Matrix4f right, Matrix4f dest)
```

So, to achieve post-multiplication, user your existing matrix as the `left` parameter, and the new matrix as the `right` parameter. If you provide a null object for `dest`, the function will allocate a new `Matrix4f` for you, and return it from the function call.

The way I usually think about matrix multiplication is that the Matrix "nearest" to the vector gets applied first. For example:

```
Perspective  *  View  *  Model  *  Vec4
```

Starting with the Matrices nearest the Vector, you can see that the Model transformation is applied first, followed by the View transformation, and then finally by the Perspective transformation.

In your code, the above would look like:

```
Matrix4f MVP = Matrix4f.mul(View, Model, null);
Matrix4f.mul(Perspective, MVP, MVP);

Vector4f result = Matrix4f.transform(MVP, Vec4, null);
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** The above is how I tend to concatenate my transforms, but since Matrix multiplication is associative, the following should also work:

```
Matrix4f MVP = Matrix4f.mul(Perspective, View, null);
Matrix4f.mul(MVP, Model, MVP);

Vector4f result = Matrix4f.transform(MVP, Vec4, null);
```